# Error while running PostgreSQL command from terrafrom local-exec

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, terraform-provider-azure, azure-postgresql

I am trying to run some PostgreSQL command after creating the PostgreSQL.

First I tried to run the psql command line on my command prompt and it works. See below screenshot

[image]

The same I would like to do from terraform so added below code and it worked. Which means that psql command is able to connect to the server.

[image]

Now the next step is to execute some command. Every time I try to run command getting "The system cannot find the file specified." error. See below screen

[image]

**Updated(11/27):** After doing hours of research below worked for me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Now the next step is to execute some command. Every time I try to run command getting "The system cannot find the file specified." error.

The error "**The system cannot find the file specified**" typically indicates that the `psql` command is unable to locate the specified file.

[image]

Here is a `PL/pgSQL` command  syntax to check the table in the database. For more details, refer to the [PLSQL doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/app-psql.html)

```
'SELECT * FROM <table-name>;
```

Here is the updated Terraform code for executing `psql` commands using Terraform.

```json
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }

    resource "null_resource" "db_setup" {
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "psql -h databasename.postgres.database.azure.com -p 5432 -U user -d postgres -c 'SELECT * FROM student;'"
        environment = {
          PGPASSWORD = "xxxxx"
        }
      }
    }
```

**Terraform result:**

[image]

**Plsql command result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer but I updated my question with working solution